# Is there an implicit import of pandas

Tags: python, pandas

In my small python project I have a function `myFunc` defined in a separate file `myFunc.py`. In my "main" program I import pandas and create a data frame (dFrame). I also import `myFunc`.

The data frame (dFrame) is passed as argument to `myFunc`, but I just realized that without importing pandas explicitly into `myFunc.py` I can still use the pandas describe function (dFrame.colname.describe()) to my surprise.

Does this mean that I have some implicit import of pandas or am I using some other function that behaves the same?

Comment: You don't import into specific functions. Once you import something, it's available in the entire script.

Comment: you imported myFunc into your main, which has panda imported. You are running myFunc in your main's "environment"

Comment: If you defined your `import myFunc` in your global scope, it would be available to all your code inside that module. However, if you state the `import myFunc` inside a code block (after if statement for example), it would be available only to the local code block

Comment: You should read about duck typing.  myFunc can call whatever method it wants on its argument.  Python doesn't know or care what type the argument is.

Comment: Hi, and thank's for your replies. what I still don't understand is that as far as I can see the same thing doesn't work with leaving out:

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from myFunc.py. About duck typing - I really expect that the methods used in myFunc.py must a) be available through import (explicit or implicit (?)) and b) apply to the type of the argument.